# Testing Contract Payable

Tags: solidity, truffle

Using **truffle** and `truffle test` I have the below test code:

```
  function testBuyItem() public {
    uint8 expected = 2;
    bytes32 expectedName = "Item";

    Assert.equal(uint(8), uint(7), "Should fail");

    contract.buy.value(1 ether)(expected);
    var (typeId, name, condition) = contract.getUserItem(1);

    Assert.equal(expectedName, name, "Should be Item");
  }
```

It doesn't fail, even if I have a failing test ABOVE the contract.buy.value(1 ether)(expected) line.  If I comment out the `contract.buy...` line it fails as expected.  The code for buy has a payable modifier than checks the value of `msg.value` with require.

Comment: Sometimes truffle can fail to recompile contracts, try deleting `build/` directory and recompile everything.